# Concurrency issue in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

We have deployed our application in two application servers(Tomcat Server) with clustering environment. Now request is coming from two servers at the same time so concurrency issue is happening it means it's creating duplicate entries in database.
Scenario is :
 1. Request (Transaction) A Update data
 2. Request (Transaction) B Update data at a same time
 3. Two row will be added into that table. among that one is duplicate.

Let's say I have methods with following signature

Request A

```
updateData() {  
  //get entity manager
  //start transcation tx
  //persist
  //commit tx
}
```

Request B

```
updateData() {
  //get entity manager
  //start transcation tx
  //persist
  //commit tx
}
```

We want to prevent scenarios like this. Request A only should persist a data into that table. Help us to solve this issue. #thanks
Environment details:   JPA 2.1 and Oracle database

Comment: Why  does update operation insert rows? Or do you mean to say that the second update overwrites the first update, without the second update not knowing about the first.

Comment: Is there any way for the application to tell they are duplicate requests?  Maybe something uniquely identifies the object, and mark that field or set of fields in the database as unique, as this would cause the second transaction to fail.  Otherwise, you need to look at solutions within your server itself so that the 'same' request doesn't get duplicated and sent to multiple servers.

Comment: Aren't there any unique constraints on the table that prevents the second request to fail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to tell that 2 concurrent messages are equivalent and only one of them should create records in the database. With inserts, it is impossible to make one insert prevent another insert coming from a different request. JPA Locks do not help here as new rows do not share anything in common. If you may think of a DB constraint that would prevent the second insert after the first insert happened, then the constraint could be your solution.

If you have some sort of correlation id, which is same for both requests, then you may create an additional log table and try to store that correlation id into that table. It is then easy to put a unique constraint on that log table, so that ine correlation id can be stored only once, and any subsequent attempt to store an entity with that id will be rolled back.